# Quasar2 Vue3 Cypress Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deep')

Tags: cypress, vuejs3, quasar-framework, cypress-component-test-runner

I have the following component test:

```
import AutoGeneratedPage from '../../../src/components/AutoGenerate/AutoGenerate.vue'; // <= note the absence of `.vue` extension, here we are importing the JS/TS part of a Double File Component
describe('AutoGenerated Page tests', () => {
  it('Auto generated page from JSON should contain all the UI Elements', () => {
    cy.mount(AutoGeneratedPage);
    cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').eq(false);
    cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').focus().click();
    cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').eq(true);
    cy.get('[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]').should('have.text', 'Option 1');
    cy.get('[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]').should('have.text', 'Option 2');
    cy.get('[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]').should('have.text', 'Option 3');
  });
})
```

and bump into the following error when running the component test:
What do I miss? https://github.com/khteh/quasar
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `mount()` and all references to quasar UI stuff. `mount()` must only be used for Component Tests. Not E2E tests.

Answer (score 0):

The first assertion needs changing:

```js
cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').eq(false);
cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').focus().click();
cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').eq(true);
```

change to

```js
cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').invoke('val').should('eq', false);
cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').focus().click();
cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').invoke('val').should('eq', true);
```

because `.eq(number)` is a Cypress command for taking the nth item in a group.

---

The error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deep')** is due to the deep rendering (i.e nested components) in the `AutoGenerate.vue` component.

If you comment out the child components, the test succeeds.

```html
<div v-for="(field, index) in layoutObj.data" :key="index">
  <span>{{field.name}}</span>
  <!-- <toggle-setting
    v-if="field.type === 'toggle'"
    :name="field.name"
    :fieldName="field.fieldName"
    :description="field.description"
    :data-test="`toggle-setting-${index}`"
  />
  <pop-up-edit-setting
    v-if="field.type === 'popUpEdit'"
    :dataType="field.dataType"
    :name="field.name"
    :fieldName="field.fieldName"
    :hint="field.hint"
    :data-test="`popup-edit-setting-${index}`"
  />
  <drop-down-setting
    v-if="field.type === 'dropDown'"
    :name="field.name"
    :description="field.description"
    :fieldName="field.fieldName"
    :internalOptions="internalOptions"
    :data-test="`dropdown-setting-${index}`"
  /> -->
</div>
```

Of course, the child components are required, but I thought I'd post this in case it gives you clues.

In any case, the Cypress component test is configured correctly, this is the  config I used.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    ...
  },
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "vue",
      bundler: "webpack",      
      webpackConfig,
    },
    specPattern: 'test/cypress/components/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    indexHtmlFile: 'test/cypress/support/component-index.html',
  },
});
```

Will add to this if I find out the problem with deep-nested components.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion but to no avail. Same error.

Comment: Ok it's something else - but you do need that change anyway.

Comment: Also the 3rd assertion.

Comment: Actually that's still not right!

Comment: Just tried. Still the same error.

Comment: Presume the toggle control is an `<input>`, you also need to put `invoke('val')` to extract the inner value, then check it has false and true.

Comment: Yeah there appears to be more than one thing wrong, but the above is the only one can see in the code. Do you have a repo, I can try to get the error coming from `mount()` command.

Comment: https://github.com/khteh/quasar

Comment: `cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').invoke('val').should('eq', false);` doesn't work. I get `expect '' to equal false` error.

Comment: I should have spotted that - the result of `.invoke('val')` is always a string (never number or boolean). What do you get after the click() (comment out the above line so the test can run passed the click()).

Comment: This works: `cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').should("not.be.checked");`.However, after `click()`, the UI shows the correct state but `cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').should("be.checked");` fails. Puzzled.

Comment: Try [check()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/check) instead of click().

Comment: No, error message telling me that it can only be used on `checkbox` or `radio` button. This is a slider toggle button.

Comment: The Cypress browser UI shows it is checked though.